# Could decorator @ effect the import?

Tags: python, openpyxl, telegram-bot

I am writing a telegram bot, where I want to store the information that the user will input in a excel spreadsheet. Two libraries the I am using are teleport and openpyxl. I am facing a problem that data is not writing in excel file.

Here is my code:

```
import telebot
import openpyxl

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('results.xlsx')
ws = wb['Poll']
last_row = ws.max_row + 1

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text(message):
    if message.text == '/start':

        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Hello Welcome')
        user_id = str(message.from_user.id)
        ws.cell(row = last_row, column = 1).value = user_id #here is where the problem is


wb.save('results.xlsx')
bot.polling(none_stop=True, timeout=60)
```

The code is not giving any mistakes, moreover, if I put ws.cell line before @bot.message_handle and give some value it works. It is just not working inside the decorator. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show what "put ws.cell line before @bot.message_handle and give some value it works" looks like?

Comment: @MattM. It will just save the value into an excel file to the last row and the first column.

Comment: Nowhere in this code are you calling `handle_text`

Comment: @StephenRauch But the bot still sends the message:"Hello Welcome", to me as a user, when I enter /start

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: @ Sorry for hearing that, but this is all I currently have, the only thing that I have changed is the token, because it is individual to each bot and I do not want anybody to go and delete the bot

Answer (score 0):

Your code currently has a fixed value for the row where you write data so you will always overwrite the same cells. Much better simply to append to the worksheet:

`ws.append([user_id])`

Comment: Thanks, but that would not fix the problem